# How to tell if a function is biased

Tags: unbiased-estimator, equivalence

I have a function that I want to see if its calculations are biased (I think, but an not certain, in the sense of an unbiased estimator).

So, I have (can generate) a set of numbers (drawn from a normal distribution with mean of 0 and standard deviation of 1) and I have two computations that calculate the same mathematical function over subsets of these numbers. One in double precision floating point, which we use as our reference data, but it is still an approximation to the real mathematical result. The second, which is the function I want to test, makes a different approximation to the actual result.  (Note that the numbers themselves are approximations to some measurement that was taken, but in my testing they are simply some values that fit a Gaussian distribution.)

And the question I want to answer is whether the function I am testing (the second one) is an unbiased approximation to the actual result. Thus, my desired hypothesis to disprove is that the function gives biased results. And, I'd like to establish that the results generated are at the equivalent to a 99% confidence level an unbiased approximation the actual result.

What I'd like is some formula based on means, standard deviations, or something else I can calculate on the results generated by my function that tell me how confident that the results are unbiased. E.g. like a p-value, but one that establishes similarity rather than difference. All the confidence interval tutorials I read have made wider ranges when you have more confidence. I think I want a narrower range. (And the last stats class I took was probably circa 1978, so I am rusty to put it mildly.)

---

To give a more concrete example, assume my function is a simple sum of some (user chosen, from my point of view random) subset of the numbers. The mean of such sums (over large enough subset) is going to have the same mean of 0. However, the standard deviation is going to be impacted by the number of elements chosen in the subset. Larger subsets, larger standard deviations. There is a standard formula to calculate it.  However, my main interest is that the mean value of such computations approximates the actual mean and does so without introducing "bias"

So, with the first function, doing a set of double precision sums gives approximately the correct estimate of the true value.  There is some error do to rounding, but we will assume that that error is Gaussian and will effectively cancel out.  That's not actually true, but it is close enough and we would say it is an unbiased estimator of the actual sum.

So, now we use our other function and it is more approximate, but the question is whether that approximation introduces "bias", or at what confidence level can we say the it is likely an unbiased estimator of the actual sum.

---

The closest I have come to something that I might be able to use to establish that is:

https://www.real-statistics.com/students-t-distribution/equivalence-testing-tost/

---

Note that I can generate "large" sets of sums to do the comparison and one of the relevant questions is how large a set I need to generate to be able to say that we are 99% or (99.5%) confident that the value returned by the function will give us an unbiased estimate of the actual value.

And, we want an unbiased estimate such that larger sums don't accumulate more bias rendering them worse estimations.  (Variance/deviation is ok as long as it is roughly Gaussian.)

Comment: Welcome to CV, Christopher. You ask your question so generally and vaguely that it doesn't really work here on CV, where we focus on specific problems.  A full and correct answer would be a textbook on statistical estimation.  Could you therefore edit your post to describe what your function is doing and approximating?